# Populate form fields with selected value of previously selected form fields

Tags: javascript, forms

I am doing a holiday booking form using RS Form with Joomla whereby I want answers from  previous questions to automatically populate the answer for other questions so that, for example, the answer to 'what airline is person 1 travelling on?' automatically populates the answer to 'what airline is person 2 travelling on?'.

I am able to do this for simple text fields when a check box (id=samedetails20 in code below) is checked. When checked, the following works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function repeat(f) {
  if(f.samedetails20.checked == true) {

f.airline2.value = f.airline1.value;
f.Airport2.value = f.Airport1.value;
f.flightno2.value = f.flightno1.value;
f.airlinereturn2.value = f.airlinereturn1.value;
  }
}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="" size="20" name="form[airline2]" id="airline2" class="rsform-input-box">`
```

However, the form also includes a drop down list to select arrival/departure times and a pop up calendar for arrival/departure dates. I do  not know how to get the values from these to automatically populate the other fields.

I have tried to use selectedIndex and options but this does not work or I am doing something wrong e.g.

```
f.DepartureTime2.value = f.DepartureTime1.options[f.DepartureTime1.selectedIndex].value;
```

Sample HTML

```
<select name="form[DepartureTime2][]" id="DepartureTime2" class="rsform-select-box"><option value="00">00</option><option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option>
```

etc.

I also have no idea how to do this for the pop-up calendar:

Sample HTML:

```
<input id="txtcal9_1" name="form[dateofdeparture1]" type="text" class="txtCal rsform-calendar-box" value="Departure date"> (Departure Date is a default value until date is selected)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Can you show some more code so we understand your problem better?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client-side only.  No values are sent to the server, and JS must work with only what it's got on the client machine (that is, what it's received from the server).

This means that when the new page is sent after a page reload (like a refresh or form submit or new window), Javascript is sent fresh values.  The old ones are gone, unless your browser ( = client side) remembers what you typed in an `<input>` box for some reason.

So, no, you can't do this in just Javascript.  You'll need something server-side like PHP or ASP or JSP to receive your values server-side, process them, and send them back to the client for Javascript to use.